# How To upload iOS build to our own website and auto update the in house apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, auto-update, ipa, in-house-distribution

I'm working on one app, it is in development stage only. I want to upload the build into my local server or website with Normal developer program instead of Enterprise program, for that i generated build for AdHoc build and generated manifest.plist file along with the build. At the time of giving AppUrl i given my local host AppUrl, and display icon url and fullscreen image url. But these two image urls are not existed in server and generated the build and uploaded the manifest.plist and .ipa file to the host. My app will automatically update when there is any available updates on local host, but the app is not downloading the update. I used the below url for download the update

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mydomain/nativeApp/manifest.plist
```

In the manifest.plist the app url is like below

```
https://mydomain/nativeApp/MyApp.ipa
```

In Index.html also im using the below tag

```
        <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://10.10.10.230:3001/manifest.plist"><font size="+4">Install the App</font></a>
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does the device log say when you open the URL?

Comment: It displaying cannot connect to <my domain>(means my local host)

Comment: should it not just be `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url==https://10.10.10.230:3001/manifest.plist` ?

Comment: Verify your local host to conform to App Transport Security requirements.

Comment: Does your localhost has ssl configured? Because AFAIK apple doesnt allow downloads without ssl anymore.

Comment: @cekisakurek Yeah, I used self signed ssl and the server is node.js here I stored .ipa, manifest.plist and provisioning profiles also.

Comment: @Wain Any other ways, i also set MIME types at server side

Comment: I dont think self-signed ssl certificates works. Maybe you should try with dropbox to make sure your ipa and html files are correct.

Comment: I had my backend team, they are holding with authorized ssl certificates and also tried in their server, same thing repeats here also.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to generating the build with normal developer account added all certificates and generating the build as AdHoc purpose and generated along with manifest file and saved the ipa, manifes.plist files and provisioning profile and ssl for that provising file in the server, but same issue repeating for local host with self signed ssl and authorized ssl as well.